# Proving the Formula of the Posterior Predictive Check

Tags: probability, bayesian

I am trying to understand where the formula used in Posterior Predictive Check comes from:

$$P(y^* | y) = \int p(y^*|\theta) p(\theta|y) d\theta$$

Where:

- $y^*$ is the new data
- $y$ is the original data
- $\theta$ are the model parameters
- $p(\theta |y)$ is the posterior probability distribution
- $p(y^* |y)$ is the probability of observing new data based on the existing data
- $p(y^* |\theta)$ is the probability of observing new data based on your model (i.e. the likelihood)

In the above equation, we first generate a random realization of $\theta_i$ from the posterior distribution, and then generate a random value of $y_i$ from the likelihood's distribution centered around $\theta_i$. If the model fits the data well, then in general :

$$P(y^* \mid y) \approx P(y)$$

Here is my attempt to derive the formula used in Posterior Predictive Check:

**Step 1:** For argument sake, let's write (using the Law of Conditional Probability):

$$P(y^*, \theta \mid y) = \frac{P(y^*, \theta, y)}{P(y)}$$

**Step 2:** Now, let's focus just on ${P(y^*, \theta, y)}$.

If we say that $A =y^*$ and $B=\theta, y$, then:

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A \mid B)P(B)$$
$$P(y^*, \theta , y) = {P(y^* | \theta, y)} \cdot P(\theta, y)$$

**Step 3:** Going back to Step 1, we can take the result from Step 2 and write:

$$P(y^*, \theta \mid y) = \frac{P(y^*, \theta, y)}{P(y)} = \frac{{P(y^* | \theta, y)} \cdot P(\theta, y)}{P(y)}$$

We can also see that:

$$P(\theta \mid y) = \frac{P(\theta, y)}{P(y)}$$

Thus, we can re-write it as:

$$P(y^*, \theta \mid y) = \frac{P(y^*, \theta, y)}{P(y)} = {P(y^* | \theta, y)} \cdot P(\theta | y)$$

**Step 4:** Now, we integrate both sides with respect to $\theta$:

$$\int P(y^*, \theta \mid y) \, d\theta = \int {P(y^* | \theta, y)} \cdot P(\theta | y) \, d\theta$$

From here, the Left Hand Side loses the integral - thus we can write:

$$P(y^* \mid y) = \int {P(y^* | \theta, y)} \cdot P(\theta | y) \, d\theta$$

**Here is where I am stuck.**

I don't know how I can further simplify :

$$P(y^* \mid y) = \int {P(y^* | \theta, y)} \cdot P(\theta | y) \, d\theta$$

$$P(y^* \mid y) = \int {P(y^* | \theta)} \cdot P(\theta | y) \, d\theta$$

I read this has to do with a conditional independence assumption, i.e. $P(y^* | \theta, y) = P(y^* | \theta)$ ... but I am not quite sure why this assumption is justified in this case.

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Answer (score 5):

If you assume the  model $\theta\to y$ and $\theta\to y^*$  then conditional on $\theta$, $y$ and $y^*$ are independent. Therefore $P(y^*|y,\theta)=P(y^*|\theta)$

Proof:
$$
P(y,y^*,\theta)=P(y|\theta)P(y^*|\theta)P(\theta)
$$
Conditioning on $\theta:$
$$
P(y,y^*|\theta)=\frac{P(y|\theta)P(y^*|\theta)P(\theta)}{P(\theta)}=P(y|\theta)P(y^*|\theta)
$$